# Running setTimeout in different context?

Tags: javascript, scope, settimeout

Is it possible to run the `setTimeout` function in another context using `call` or `apply`? I tried but they returned error saying "illegal invocation".

```js
var myvar = 10;

function myfun() {
    console.log("normal run "+myvar);
}

var myobjvar = {
    myvar : 26,
    myfun1 : function() {
        console.log("context run "+this.myvar1);
    }
}

setTimeout(myfun, 1000);

setTimeout.call(myobjvar, myobjvar.myfun1, 1000) // errors out!!
```

Comment: Please add code here

Comment: The function passed to *setTimeout* is called form the global execution context and has it's own execution context. You can set the function's *this* in the usual ways.

Comment: All the regular stuff - use `.bind` or ES6 arrow functions or the `self = this` hack etc.

Comment: @RobG  - could you demo in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum - Please demo in jsfiddle

Comment: *setTimeout.call* will set the *this* of setTimeout, it seems you want to set the *this* of the function passed to setTimeout. Maybe `setTimeout(function(){myobjvar.myfun1()}, 1000)`.

Answer (score 2):

`Function.call` and `Function.apply` let you change the binding of the `this` keyword inside a function. But when you use `setTimeout`, you don't need to do that because `setTimeout` doesn't use `this` at all - or if it does, you shouldn't know about it.

Instead, you want to change the meaning of `this` inside the function itself. You can do that with `Function.bind`:

```
setTimeout( myobjvar.myfun1.bind(myobjvar), 1000);
```

This is essentially the same as either of these:

```
setTimeout( function(){ myobjvar.myfun1() }, 1000);
setTimeout( function(){ myobjvar.myfun1.call(myobjvar) }, 1000);
```

Comment: The use of call in the last option is redundant.

Comment: @RobG, yes. But it better illustrates what `bind` is doing because the `this`-binding is more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set context.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/agLf4ahs/1/)

```js
var myvar = 10;

function myfun() {
    console.log('normal run ' + myvar);
}

var myobjvar = {
    myvar : 26,
    myfun1 : function() {
        console.log('context run ' + this.myvar);
    }
}

setTimeout(myfun, 1000);
setTimeout(myobjvar.myfun1.bind(myobjvar), 1000);
```

Comment: @anandpatil `var myvar = 10;` !== `this.myvar = 10;`, maybe you confuse these concepts? The first is a variable and the second is an object property.  For example, using an object property instead variable in your case: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/wknye11d/).

Comment: Oh! so isn't var myvar = 10 creating a property in window object in this case? could you explain in a little more details? would be helpful.

Comment: @anandpatil yes, `var myvar = 10;` creates `window.myvar = 10;` only when you're in global scope. I think when you write different snippets on different sites (here or https://jsfiddle.net for example), default scope for code from an editor is not global scope. If you execute [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/wknye11d/2/) on https://jsfiddle.net and different place with global scope (your browser's console or your own HTML page), you'll get different results.